# In UWP applications, can I get the list of SSL certificate errors after establishing connection?

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl, uwp

In a UWP application, I can set something like this to enable self-signed certificates when connecting StreamSocket to an SSL-enabled host:

```
streamSocket.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);
streamSocket.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("localhost"), "993", SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12);
```

However, I would like to make it possible for the application to examine which errors actually occurred during the connection. I thought I'd use this:

```
streamSocket.Information.ServerCertificateErrors
```

However, this collection is empty in my tests. It only gets populated in case when streamSocket.Control.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors is empty and thus the connection is aborted with an exception. I would like to have the connection established (i.e. SSL errors ignored) but still have these errors recorded and available for the application (like I did before with SslStream and .NET Framework). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, if we add `ChainValidationResult.InvalidName` and `ChainValidationResult.Untrusted` to the [`StreamSocketControl.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketcontrol.ignorableservercertificateerrors.aspx) before we run the [`StreamSocket.ConnectAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.connectasync.aspx) method, it will ignore the SSL server errors. That we can not get any `ChainValidationResult` in [`StreamSocketInformation.ServerCertificateErrors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketinformation.servercertificateerrors.aspx).

We should be able to use the `StreamSocket.ConnectAsync` method without adding the `ChainValidationResult.InvalidName` and `ChainValidationResult.Untrusted`.

There is an official sample about StreamSocket, please refer the [Certificates in Scenario5](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/StreamSocket/cs/Scenario5_Certificates.xaml).

We should be able to use [try-catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) to catch the exception of the `StreamSocket.ConnectAsync` method. Then we can get the `ChainValidationResult` in `StreamSocketInformation.ServerCertificateErrors` and we can add the `ChainValidationResult` to the `StreamSocketControl.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors`. Also we should be able to use the `StreamSocket.ConnectAsync` again.

Comment: Thanks. Making connection twice was the obvious way of doing things, I just wanted to make sure this is the only solution. Seems it is.